# How to Span<T> and stackalloc to create a temporary small list

Tags: c#, optimization, memory, memory-management

I was reading a description of some code written in C that gains speed due to allocating temporary arrays on the stack instead of the heap for use in very hot loops. (It was described as being similar to SBO optimization). The object in question is similar to a `List<T>` in that it's just an array with some basic convenience functionality on top. It allocates a small section of memory to use, and if the list is expanded past the size of the array, it allocates a new array on the heap, copies the data, and updates the pointer.

I would like to do the same thing in C#, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it as I want to keep this in a `safe` context so I can't use a pointer to update the data reference if its expanded, and `Span<int>` doesn't have an implicit cast to `int[]`. Specifically:

- `stackalloc` memory is released on method exit, so I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to use a struct like this than giving it a Span field and assigning it after creating within the method using it.
- How do I neatly switch between using backing fields of different types (Span and int[]) without changing the public-facing interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution, not sure if it's the best implementation, but it seems to work. I also have a couple of alternatives.

**Note:** This is useful for increasing speed only when you have a function that needs to create a temporary array and is called *very* frequently. The ability to switch to a heap allocated object is just a fallback in case you overrun the buffer.

**Option 1 - Using [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1#properties) and `stackalloc`**

If you're building to .NET Core 2.1 or later, .NET Standard 2.1 or later, or can use NuGet to use the [System.Memory package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/), the solution is really simple.

Instead of a class, use a `ref struct` (this is necessary to have a `Span<T>` field, and neither can leave the method where they're declared. If you need a long-lived class, then there's no reason to try to allocate on the stack since you'll just have to move it to the heap anyway.)

```
public ref struct SmallList
{
    private Span<int> data;
    private int count;
    //...
}
```

Then add in all your list functionality. `Add()`, `Remove()`, etc. In Add or any functions that might expand the list, add a check to make sure you don't overrun the span.

```
if (count == data.Length)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[data.Length * 2]; //double the capacity
    Array.Copy(data.ToArray(), 0, new_array, 0, cap);
    data = new_array;  //Implicit cast! Easy peasy!
}
```

`Span<T>` can be used to work with stack allocated memory, but it can also point to heap allocated memory. So if you can't guarantee your list will always be small enough to fit in the stack, the snippet above gives you a nice fallback that shouldn't happen frequently enough to cause noticeable problems. If it is, either increase the initial stack allocation size (within reason, don't overflow!), or use another solution like an array pool.

Using the struct just requires an extra line and a constructor that takes a span to assign to the `data` field. Not sure if there's a way to do it all in one shot, but it's easy enough:

```
Span<int> span = stackalloc int[32];
SmallList list = new SmallList(span);
```

And if you need to use it in a nested function (which was part of my issue) you just pass it in as a parameter instead of having the nested function return a list.

```
void DoStuff(SmallList results) { /* do stuff */ }

DoStuff(list);
//use results...
```

**Option 2: ArrayPool**

The System.Memory package also includes the `ArrayPool` class, which lets you store a pool of small arrays that your class/struct could take out without bothering the garbage collector. This has comparable speed depending on the use case. It also has the benefit that it would work for classes that have to live beyond a single method. It's also fairly easy to write your own if you can't use `System.Memory`.

**Option 3: Pointers**

You can do something like this with pointers and other `unsafe` code, but the question was technically asking about `safe` code. I just like my lists to be thorough.

**Option 4: Without System.Memory**

If, like me, you're using Unity / Mono, you can't use System.Memory and related features until [at least 2021](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1330#issuecomment-510495179). Which leaves you to roll your own solution. An array pool is fairly straightforward to implement, and does the job of avoiding garbage allocations. A stack allocated array is a bit more complicated.

Luckily, [someone has already done it](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/5051), specifically with Unity in mind. The page linked is quite long, but includes both sample code demonstrating the concept and a code generation tool that can make a `SmallBuffer` class specific to your exact use case. The basic idea is to just create a struct with individual variables that you index as if they were an array.
**Update:** I tried both these solutions and the array pool was slightly faster (and a lot easier) than the SmallBuffer in my case, so remember to profile!

Answer (score -3):

In C and C++ languages the developer defines in which memory an object is going to be instantiated: stack or heap. 
In C# you it is determined by the author of the data type. 
You can achieve your goal using Span and pointers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1. 
But I would not recommend you to do that, because your code is not safe. Meaning that CLR gives you all the responsibility to manage it, at least clean the memory, when you do not need such object anymore. Usually the C# developers come to such tricks, when they want to optimise really big data collections, which allocates a lot of memory in the heap.
If it is still what you are looking for - than, probably, C# is not the best option to use. 
Even more, if you have a big collection and somehow you find the way how to put it in stack memory - you can easily face StackOverflowException.

Comment: Will that cliche "probably, C# is not the best option" for all performance related tasks ever die...?