# Is there a way, to conditionally allocate some fixed-size-stack buffer?

Tags: c#, stackalloc

pretty much tittle!

imagine this here:

```
public unsafe ConditionalAllocOnStack
{
    private fixed byte STACK[CONDITION_TRUE ? 100 : 0];

    public ConditionalAllocOnStack()
    {
         //....
    }     
}
```

Anyway to make this possible, with the managed ways or unmanged/unsafe ways.

Would be neat to know this, and a little appele:

Pls, I respect all opionions and think critically on them, even if some1 say "i would not do what u doing " and so on.. But pls just for the sake of curiosity I would love to know if such constructs are possible :)

Thx

Comment: [`stackalloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) perhaps?

Comment: @Charlieface how so, even stackalloc needs a fixed size ?

Comment: can u make an example?

Comment: `stackalloc` can use a variable size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Span<T> and stackalloc to create a temporary small list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523965/how-to-spant-and-stackalloc-to-create-a-temporary-small-list)